# Launch Agent not running Bash File

Tags: terminal, bash, launchd, path

I have a bash script `imagecopy.sh` that backups images which are located in a subdirectory with a prepended date string: this works perfectly fine when I execute it from the directory it resides in - `/Users/danny/Library/Caches/`.

***The script is***

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cat himawaripy/latest.png > himawaripy/output/$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S").png
```

I have also added the directory where the script is located to my `$PATH`using `nano .profile` and confirmed this using `echo $PATH`.

```
/Users/danny/Library/Caches:/Users/danny/anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin
```

I would like to run the bash script periodically using a LaunchAgent, located in `/Users/danny/Library/LaunchAgents`.

The LaunchAgent file `com.user.imagecopier.plist`references the script location by the lines..

```
..other code

<key>Program</key>
<string>imagecopy.sh</string>

...etc
```

I presume there is a mistake linking the LaunchAgent file to the script, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** Updated LaunchAgent File as Suggested

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.user.imagecopier</string>

  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/Users/danny/Library/Caches/imagecopy.sh</string>
  </array>

  <key>Nicer</key>
  <integer>1</integer>

  <key>StartInterval</key>
  <integer>60</integer>

  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>

</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Why are you using `cat` to copy files? Use the key `ProgramArguments` with the absolute path to the script. And the absolute paths to the source file and destination file within your script.

Comment: Thanks @fd0 ! With the changes you suggested (absolute paths) the script now runs successfully from any directory. unfortunately LaunchAgent is still not functional... I have added the updated file for reference.

Comment: The script should contain absolute paths as well (or set PATH itself at the beginning), not only the LaunchAgent plist. Also `cat`ing a file to another looks kind of strange, just use `cp` (if you want to keep the source file) or `mv` (if you only want to rename it).

Comment: Ah, and why are you using `<key>ProgramArguments</key>` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To store a shell script in a Caches folder is **very uncommon**!
2. If you use absolute paths in your script and the plist you don't have to add obscure paths to your PATH variable.

Clean up your .profile/.bash_profile file and remove the /Users/danny/Library/Caches: part!

Create a bin folder in your user folder and put in a script with the name *imagecopy.sh*. The content of the script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
cp /Users/danny/Library/Caches/latest.png /Users/danny/Documents/output/$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S").png
```

Create an appropriate output folder. In the example above I use ~/Documents/output.

Create the file /Users/danny/Library/LaunchAgents/com.user.imagecopier.plist with the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.user.imagecopier</string>
    <key>Nicer</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/danny/bin/imagecopy.sh</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/com.user.imagecopier.stderr</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/com.user.imagecopier.stdout</string>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>60</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The file /tmp/com.user.imagecopier.stderr will show any error (e.g. if the output folder is missing or no latest.png is available)

Load the file with:

```
launchctl load -w /Users/danny/Library/LaunchAgents/com.user.imagecopier.plist
```

If the launch agent works properly you can remove the part

```
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/com.user.imagecopier.stderr</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/com.user.imagecopier.stdout</string>
```

of the plist.

Comment: thanks! this looks like a more sustainable/neater solution. after a system restart my initial attempts worked, but I think I will adapt to this protocol.